# Why is the final array returning 7 rows of the last array compiled instead of the 7 unique array values in Google Apps Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

Sorry, I'm pretty new to this but I do extras casting and need to get stats of who and what types I have working and would like build the template so I can reference it later to start counting and displaying the stats.

My code:

```
function myFunction ()  {
  var UNIQUE_ETHNIC = ["w","b","h","a","m","e","o"];
  var UNIQUE_GENDER = ["m","f"];
  var UNIQUE_AGE = ["20","30","40","50","60","70"];
  var egaArray =  calculateEga(UNIQUE_ETHNIC, UNIQUE_GENDER, UNIQUE_AGE); 
}

function calculateEga(ethnicUnique, genderUnique, ageUnique) {  
  var returnedArray = [[],[]];
  var tempArray = [];
  for (eU = 0; eU < ethnicUnique.length; eU++) {
    var columnCounter = 0;
    for (gU = 0; gU < genderUnique.length; gU++) {    
      for (aU = 0; aU < ageUnique.length; aU++) {
        tempArray[columnCounter] = ethnicUnique[eU]+genderUnique[gU]+ageUnique[aU];
        columnCounter++; //used so male & female on one line
        }
    }
    Logger.log(tempArray); //this gives the right array here each time
    returnedArray[eU] = tempArray; 
    //returnedArray[eU] = ['ega: '+tempArray];  //outputs what I kind of need

  }
  Logger.log(returnedArray); // 7 dupes of the last compiled array
  return returnedArray;
}
```

--- The 1st Logger.log spits out the correct tempArray values however once I stick them in the returnedArray it just gives me 7 dupes of the last compiled array thus the last Logger.log is giving this:

[[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70],

[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70],

[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70],

[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70],

[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70],

[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70],

[om20, om30, om40, om50, om60, om70, of20, of30, of40, of50, of60, of70]]

But if I use that commented out 'ega: ' call instead I get the much closer to what I'm aiming for version:

[ega: wm20,wm30,wm40,wm50,wm60,wm70,wf20,wf30,wf40,wf50,wf60,wf70],

[ega: bm20,bm30,bm40,bm50,bm60,bm70,bf20,bf30,bf40,bf50,bf60,bf70],

[ega: hm20,hm30,hm40,hm50,hm60,hm70,hf20,hf30,hf40,hf50,hf60,hf70],

[ega: am20,am30,am40,am50,am60,am70,af20,af30,af40,af50,af60,af70],

[ega: mm20,mm30,mm40,mm50,mm60,mm70,mf20,mf30,mf40,mf50,mf60,mf70],

[ega: em20,em30,em40,em50,em60,em70,ef20,ef30,ef40,ef50,ef60,ef70],

[ega: om20,om30,om40,om50,om60,om70,of20,of30,of40,of50,of60,of70]]

Would like to get the later version but w/out the 'ega: '

Thank you for any help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, the value of `tempArray` might be put to the array of `returnedArray` as the pass by reference. From your sample values, it seems that all values are the last array of `tempArray`. By this, when `'ega: '+tempArray` is used, the pass by value is run and the expected array is obtained. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
returnedArray[eU] = tempArray;
```

#### To:

```
returnedArray[eU] = tempArray.slice();
```

or

```
returnedArray[eU] = tempArray.concat();
```

or

```
returnedArray[eU] = [...tempArray];
```

- In this case, I thought that other methods are also existing.

#### Testing:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var UNIQUE_ETHNIC = ["w", "b", "h", "a", "m", "e", "o"];
  var UNIQUE_GENDER = ["m", "f"];
  var UNIQUE_AGE = ["20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70"];
  var egaArray = calculateEga(UNIQUE_ETHNIC, UNIQUE_GENDER, UNIQUE_AGE);
  console.log(egaArray)
}

function calculateEga(ethnicUnique, genderUnique, ageUnique) {
  var returnedArray = [[], []];
  var tempArray = [];
  for (eU = 0; eU < ethnicUnique.length; eU++) {
    var columnCounter = 0;
    for (gU = 0; gU < genderUnique.length; gU++) {
      for (aU = 0; aU < ageUnique.length; aU++) {
        tempArray[columnCounter] = ethnicUnique[eU] + genderUnique[gU] + ageUnique[aU];
        columnCounter++;
      }
    }
    returnedArray[eU] = tempArray.slice();
  }
  return returnedArray;
}

myFunction();
```

#### References:

- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you!  the concat() totally worked!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am new to this site and don't see the "accept" button ;)